# Find and get row index in datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

## DataTable.Select problem

i have simple datatable like this

```
|   1  |  2   |   3  |
|------|------|------|
| 1966 | 6544 | 1967 | 
| 9560 | 3339 | 4968 | 
| 0    | 9400 | 1765 | 
| 0    | 5479 | 6701 |
```

for example i want to check if 1966 is already exist in column "1" and if it exist get row index
i do code like this

```
Dim search() As DataRow = table.Select(" '" & i & "' = '" & value & "'   ")
  'where i is a integer from 1 to 3 and value is a biginteger
    If search.Count > 0 Then
        'get row index
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("not found")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the row index is contained in the values of the rows themselves you'll have to abandon the Select method and use a cursor based approach.  This example will stop looping if a match is found:

```
Dim intTargetIndex As Integer = -1
Dim intCursor As Integer = 0

Do Until intCursor = table.Rows.Count OrElse intTargetIndex > -1

    If table.Rows(intCursor)(0).ToString() = value.ToString() Then

        intTargetIndex = intCursor

    End If

    intCursor += 1

Loop
```

Comment: your code worked fine to my problem,, but whether its better than using **table.Select**?..  @NoAlias

Comment: I'm guessing that this will be a little faster than the table.Select method.  First, it will stop upon finding a single match (similar to .Any() vs .Count() > 0), secondly .IndexOf may be more expensive.  The best way to know for sure would be to profile both methods.

Answer (score 7):

Using your existing loop, just find the row in the table:

```
Dim ndx As Int32
Dim rows = dtSample.Select("Id = 42")
If rows.Count > 0 Then
    ndx = dtSample.Rows.IndexOf(rows(0))
End If
Return ndx
```

Using extension methods, you can condense it:

```
Dim ndx = dtSample.AsEnumerable().
                Where(Function(q) q.Field(Of Int32)("Id") = 42).
                Select(Function(z) dtSample.Rows.IndexOf(z)).
                ToArray()
```

`ndx` will be an array in this case, and will be empty when there is no match.

Comment: Nice use of IndexOf.

Comment: i still cannot use **table.Select**  
`Dim rows = table.Select("1 = 1966")` and use condition like this
        `'If rows.Count > 0 Then` @Plutonix

Answer (score 3):

Your query is currently trying to query number fields as strings, so if the datatable columns you're querying are indeed integers, then the correct syntax would be:

```
Dim search() As DataRow = table.Select(i.ToString & " = " & value.ToString)
```

Column names and numbers don't have single quotes around them. Then, to get the index, you will need to search the table for the index of the row you returned. DataRowCollections have a way to do that, you just need to iterate through the query's return:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In table.Select(i.ToString & " = " & value.ToString)
    MsgBox(dr.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr).ToString)
Next dr
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
Dim rowIndex = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Column_Name")).ToList().FindIndex(Function(col) col = "Find_Key")
```

Comment: Please follow the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide. Your answer misses some clarifications.

Comment: This worked great for me. Just what I needed, thanks!

I did notice that if the index does not exist, it will return the Index as -1. So you just do an "If" statement that says if the Index is greater than 0 then...Whatever you need from there.

Answer (score 0):

First, do select to your datatable, then get the row index with `For Each`.

```
Dim result() As DataRow = tblchk.Select("Device_No ='" & TxtBarcode.Text & "'")
For Each row As DataRow In result
    MsgBox(row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(row)) ''this is for row index value
Next
```